# Unable to get location updates

Tags: android, locationlistener

I made changes in my location based android app to conform to latest API.
So now my activity implements:

```
public class MapActivity extends FragmentActivity implements   LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {
.....
}
```

In `onCreate`, I configure `LocationRequest` and `GoogleApiClient`:

```
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
            .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
            .setInterval(2 * 1000);
mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();
```

And here is my `onConnected` method:

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
     Log.i(TAG, "Location services connected.");
     Location location =  LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);        
     if (location == null) {               LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient,  mLocationRequest, this);
     } else {
        .....
        .....
    }
}
```

Issue I am facing is that `onLocationChanged` is not getting called even when user is on move.

What am I missing here?

During debugging I found that in `onConnected()`:

```
Location location = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
```

The location is not null, hence code inside `if` is not executed. Can that be the reason for `onLocationChanged` not getting called?

Comment: Are you sure localization services are turned on on your smartphone?

Comment: That I am not sure....how do check that.BTW, I have googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

So when map activity is running, user location is constantly updated on map. So I guess location services is working fine.

Comment: I just checked....location services are enabled on my device.

Comment: LocationRquest is as:
         mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create()
        .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY)
        .setInterval(5000)
        .setSmallestDisplacement(25.0f);
Moved code inside if out. So now onLocationChanged called,but only once.I assume that it must be called even if position is unchanged as I have set 5 secs in setInterval.

Comment: It was related to priority level.I set it to PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY, and now calls are frequent.I expected that with PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY I would get real time location updates.But this was not the case.